# Parallel running with only limited CPU cores

Tags: xargs, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I have a 12 cores server and I want to run a script which take a file as input argument and does processing on it. I want to use 8 core and no further to do parallel processing on 8 files at a time on 8 cores and then jump to next once the processing for 1 is complete.

I have tried doing it with `xargs` like so:

```
ls /data/paths/ | grep new | xargs -i -P 8 -n 1 bash main.sh {}
```

But when I see the core the CPU utilization is attached in the snapshot.[image]

I have also tried doing with parallel as follows:

```
ls /data/paths/ | grep new | parallel -j 8 --no-notice bash main.sh {}
```

My condition that I have to keep it limited to 8 CPUs.

#### EDIT:

When I run `ps -ef | grep main.sh` it shows 11-12 processes instead of 8.

Comment: Your CPU utilization doesn't tell us anything about how many processes are started by `xargs` or `parallel`. The scheduler may well assign a process to various cores in its lifetime.

Comment: @muru when I run `ps -ef | grep main.sh` it shows 11 processes instead of 8.

Comment: That way you're counting both `grep`, and `xargs` at the least in addition to your script's processes. Possibly something else as well.

Comment: Please show info in image also as text (it is currently inaccessible).

Comment: Your utilisation is approximately 66.6% = ⅔ = 8 / 12 Therefore jobs is doing its job. However the OS, is balancing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`taskset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) to set the cpu affinity of a process. The following will make sure that your `xargs` command only uses the first 8 virtual CPU cores:

```
ls /data/paths/ | grep new | taskset -c 0-7 xargs -i -P 8 -n 1 bash main.sh {}
```

Note that from [man taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset):

> A user must possess CAP_SYS_NICE to change the CPU affinity of a process.

Comment: This is also true for GNU Parallel (`taskset` will even make it only detect 8 cores, so `-P` is not needed): `ls /data/paths/ | grep new | taskset -c 0-7 parallel bash main.sh`